# how to get all events from fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have the following code where I am trying to retrieve all the events that are in fullcalendar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fullcalendar Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.0/main.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.0/main.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="getEvents()">Click me</button>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
  <script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        editable: true,
        headerToolbar: {
            start: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        selectable: true, //can click to set event
        selectMirror: true, // so it's solid 
        unselectAuto: false, //if you click outside calendar, event doesn't disappear, but if you click inside calendar, event still disappears
        eventStartEditable: true,
        eventResizableFromStart: true,
        eventDurationEditable: true,
        select: function(selectionInfo) {
            calendar.addEvent({
              title: 'dynamic event',
              start: selectionInfo.start,
              end: selectionInfo.end //need these and not endTime/startTime, otherwise they won't re-render
            });
            calendar.unselect();
        },
        eventClick: function(eventClickInfo) {
            eventClickInfo.event.remove();
        }



      });
      calendar.render();

      function getEvents() {
        console.log(calendar.getEvents());
      }

    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button at the top of the page, in order to call the `getEvents()` function to console.log the events, I am currently getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: getEvents is not defined", which I can understand given where the function is placed, but if I place it outside the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()` block then the `calendar` variable won't be in scope and thus I won't be able to call the `getEvents()` method of the calendar. Does anyone know how else I could retrieve the events? (I later want to make a call to a post route using the data of the events when I click the button)

Answer (score 3):

You can give an id that button and listen click event by adding an `addEventListener`

**Live Demo:**

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        editable: true,
        headerToolbar: {
            start: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        selectable: true, //can click to set event
        selectMirror: true, // so it's solid 
        unselectAuto: false, //if you click outside calendar, event doesn't disappear, but if you click inside calendar, event still disappears
        eventStartEditable: true,
        eventResizableFromStart: true,
        eventDurationEditable: true,
        select: function(selectionInfo) {
            calendar.addEvent({
              title: 'dynamic event',
              start: selectionInfo.start,
              end: selectionInfo.end //need these and not endTime/startTime, otherwise they won't re-render
            });
            calendar.unselect();
        },
        eventClick: function(eventClickInfo) {
            eventClickInfo.event.remove();
        }



      });
      calendar.render();

      function getEvents() {
        console.log(calendar.getEvents());
      }
      
      document.getElementById('getevent').addEventListener('click', getEvents);

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fullcalendar Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.0/main.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.0/main.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="getevent">Click me</button>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```